# vba code to find a specific value and copy value in subsequent cell in the column and paste in a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet with some data. In Column A, it has set of data, my objective is to copy the cell value below the cell which contains its value as "Line".

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="line", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    'do it something

Else
    'do it another thing
End If
```

But it is used to find only the cell value which contains as Line.

Comment: So you want to know how to use `cell.Offset(1, 0)`?  (e.g. `something = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value`?)

Comment: Yes, I think so.@YowE3K

Answer (score 2):

To reference the cell which is one row below, and zero columns to the right of, the cell referred to by your `cell` variable you can use `cell.Offset(1, 0)`.

(Obviously, this can only be done if `cell` isn't `Nothing`, so needs to be used only in the `Else` leg of your code's `If` statement.)